# Teradata Week Number Prior Year with Monday as Start of Week

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following statement in teradata

```
case when extract(year from current_date) - 1 = extract(year from event_date)
    and weeknumber_of_year(event_date) = weeknumber_of_year(current_date) then 'Y' else 'N' end as "WTD_LY"
```

The issue is my 'week' is supposed to start on a Monday, instead of Sunday.  How would I need to tweak this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an optional parameter for `week number_of_year`:

```
weeknumber_of_year(current_date, 'ISO')
```

But you logic will fail, e.g. there's a week 53 in 2015/16, but not in 2014.